# How to make Time Series plot and mark 5 days with the highest sales in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

- date_col - in "datetime64" format
- sales - in "int64" format

  | date_col | sales |
  | --- | --- |
  | 2019-01-05 | 100 |
  | 2019-03-20 | 500 |
  | 2019-04-28 | 290 |
  | ... | ... |

And I need to create Time Series plot and mark in a separate color the 5 days with the highest number of sales.

Currently I have code like below:

```
df['sales'].plot(linewidth=1.5,
                 grid = True,
                 marker="o",
                 linestyle="-",
                 markersize=4,
                 label="Daily sales",
                 color = "steelblue")
plt.xlabel("date")
plt.ylabel("sales")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And it gives result:
[image]

But as a final result I need something like below:

- vertical lines representing 5 days with the highest sales
- date in year month day format for those 5 days with the highest sales

[image]

How can I do that in Python ? How can I modify my code or do that in other way?

mrCopiCat I used your code and I have result like below, why ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can use the `ax.annotate` function built in `matplotlib` with the `ax.vlines`. here's an example with 5 maximums (I did use simple int values for date (for the sake of the example) but it'll surely work with your datetime values):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# init figure and axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set(title="maximum sales ...")

# sample df
data = {'date_col': list(range(20)), 'sales': [random.randint(1, 30) for _ in range(20)]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('date_col')

# plotting the df
df.plot(ax=ax)

# adding the lines
num_max = 5 # change this if you want more or less points

for row in df.sort_values(by='sales', ascending=False).iloc[:num_max].iterrows():
    print(row[0], row[1])
    xmax, ymax = row[0], row[1]
    ax.vlines(xmax, 0, ymax, color="tab:red") 
    ax.annotate(f'{xmax}', xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax + 1), color="tab:red")

# setting size limit and plotting
ax.set_ylim(0,40) # change or remove that too
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: mrCopiCat I used your code and I have really bad result, I added it on my question, why I have this result ? How to fix that ? :/ Maybe type of data?

Comment: @ratus111 you forgot to change  the y limit ! its the  'ax.set_ylim(0,40)' line

Comment: remove it and it should be good (or set a value that is far from the maximum of your sales (something like 600 maybe)

Comment: Yes you are right and one more (last) question, how can I build plot using your code but also select range of date from column "date_col", for instance if I would like to see only plot for range of data between: 2019-01-01 and 2019-05-01 ?

Comment: well if your index is the date, you can simply filter by index your datafram like `df = df[start_time : end_time]` before plotting it.

Comment: df = df["2019-01-01" : "2019-05-01"] does not work, yes date is in index, how to do that ?

Comment: try this `df.index.to_series().between('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01')`